# Unexpected end of file error when executing script

Tags: linux, bash

Can somebody help me debug this simple script? I've been trying for 2 hrs now but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Search for MMSC or WAP connectivity errors"

sftpErrorCount=$(tail -100 3_ERRORs_log.txt | grep "MMSC_Upload2" | grep "Fail to copy"| awk '{print $1 " " $2" " $3" " $4}'| wc -l)

if [ "$sftpErrorCount" -gt 0 ]
then
sftpErrorDate=$(tail -100 3_ERRORs_log.txt | grep "MMSC_Upload2" | grep "Fail to copy"| awk '{print $1 " " $2" " $3" " $4}'| tail -1)
echo "Error found at around $sftpErrorDate please check FTP logs"

else
echo "No errors found"
```

Error when I execute the script:

```
$ sh test_script.sh
Search for MMSC or WAP connectivity errors
test_script.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close your if-statement with the word `fi`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Search for MMSC or WAP connectivity errors"

sftpErrorCount=$(tail -100 3_ERRORs_log.txt | grep "MMSC_Upload2" |
   grep "Fail to copy"| awk '{print $1 " " $2" " $3" " $4}'| wc -l)

if [ "$sftpErrorCount" -gt 0 ] ; then
    sftpErrorDate=$(tail -100 3_ERRORs_log.txt | grep "MMSC_Upload2" |
      grep "Fail to copy"| awk '{print $1 " " $2" " $3" " $4}'| tail -1)
    echo "Error found at around $sftpErrorDate please check FTP logs"
else
    echo "No errors found"
fi
# ^ This closes the block.
```

Also note that I made a few styling changes to your script. Indentation can make bugs like these easier to find.

Comment: Thanks alot evan! I think i should rest for a bit these is an embarassing mistake!